# What is the word that is the antonym of "monopoly"?

Tags: word-request

What is the one-word antonym of *monopoly*?

Examples:

> The postal service has a monopoly on delivering letters.
>
> AT&T used to have a monopoly on telephone service.
>
> The Smith gang has a monopoly on drug dealing on the south side.
>
> The government has a monopoly on the legal use of violence.

I was thinking about *multipoly* or *polypoly*, such as in *monotheistic* versus *polytheistic*.

Comment: I'm so tempted to answer: Scrabble.

Comment: There's "oligopoly", when a small number of companies control a market as opposed to just one. But I don't think that's what you're looking for. You could contrast "monopoly" with "free market", but without the context of a contrast, "free market" has other meanings.

Comment: And BTW, I think by definition 85% is not a monopoly. Maybe you could say "near-monopoly". You wouldn't say, "He's a monotheist: he believes in only two gods." Close but not quite.

Comment: @Jay You are right, but I couldn't find any example. Maybe this is better: e.g. The USA has monopoly on the fastest airplane in the world ;) https://sites.google.com/site/worldfastcar/airplane

Comment: The postal service has a monopoly on delivering letters. AT&T used to have a monopoly on telephone service. The Smith gang has a monopoly on drug dealing on the south side. The government has a monopoly on the legal use of violence. :-)

Comment: Ok, I will use your suggestions.

Comment: Antonyms aren't strictly defined, so you can pick whichever *you* think works as the opposite--if any antonym exists at all.  In some cases a choice is relatively obvious, but in a case like this, IMO there is no clear choice.

Answer (score 3):

*Polypoly* (also spelled *polyopoly*) comes somewhat close to the meaning you seek, but it is much less widely used than *monopoly*. It occurs mainly in the context of economics, where it describes a situation in which there are many small sellers but no large ones. *Polypoly* is also sometimes used as a synonym for *oligopoly* (see Jay's comment on your question).

Because its meaning is liable to be confused in this way, *polypoly* is not a good general antonym for *monopoly*. (Nor is *multipoly*, which native English speakers would probably regard as ‘not a real word.’) In addition to Jay's suggestions given above, you might consider describing the situation as *competitive* or as one of *free competition*.

As a side note, you can often get a sense of a word's scarcity by using Google Ngrams, which chart the frequency of a word's use in books over a period of time. [This one](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=monopoly%2Cpolypoly%2Cmultipoly&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows how often *monopoly*, *polypoly*, and *multipoly* occur in books written between 1900 and 2000. You can see that *polypoly* is extremely rare compared to *monopoly*, while *multipoly* is rarer still.

Comment: Ooh, "competitive market" would be a good term, especially if stated in contrast to a monopoly. I think that would be readily understood, even if it's not a generally-accepted antonym.